# css property to p tag splitting the text when overflow

Tags: css

I am writing content in the p tag in one of the li tag (each li tag consists of 4 p tags).

I am placing the content inside li tag. When it overflows it does not cut the string, it occupies the second p tag space. Please give some suggessions to avoid in both IE and Firefox.

```
p         p               p             p
.........................................................
rajufgsag hjfhf           fdsfg         hdsfghd
```

Comment: In the future, please post the smallest possible `<html></html>` code which exhibits the problem. Your English is honestly said very hard to follow and the ASCII art makes not much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Set the overflow setting on the li not the p.

Answer (score 0):

Define a total width on your `<li>` and then float your 4 `<p>` tags within that, each with 1/4 of the `<li>`'s width:

```
li {
    width: 200px;
}

li p {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

You shouldn't need to use the overflow property at all.